# Appium/WinAppDriver and WPF/ReactiveUI timing issue - Switching from login dialog window to application window

Tags: c#, wpf, appium, reactiveui, winappdriver

I'm trying to use Appium to test WPF application. The login dialog (ReactiveWindow) shows separate from main window application (ReactiveWindow) and in my test when I click the logon button, the login window closes and goes back to main window applicaton. The time in between the transition is causing my test to fail.

I can use Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) and test will pass. Is there a way to use a wait command to do this?

```
    var loginButton = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("LogonButton");
    loginButton.Click();


    //Thread.Sleep will work here but, is there a way to use a wait?

    var searchBox = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("SearchBox");
    searchBox.SendKeys("Test 123");
    Assert.AreEqual("Test 123", searchBox.Text);
```

**Update:**

```
var loginButton = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("LogonButton");
loginButton.Click();

//Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

do
{
    try
    {
        var searchBox = session.FindElementByAccessibilityId("SearchBox");
        searchBox.SendKeys("Test 123");
        Assert.AreEqual("Test 123", searchBox.Text);
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception) { /* try again */ }

} while (true);
```

The preceding seems to work, any objections or insights?

Comment: Rod, what is your "session" variable? Is it something like this:                                      
                protected static WindowsDriver<RemoteWebElement> session;

Answer (score 0):

No, because there is nothing to wait for as far as the code being tested in concerned. You just click a button synchronously and what happens next and how long you'll have to wait for this to happen is undeterminstic to Appium and your test.

That's why it's recommended to write your application logic in view models or services that can be tested independently from the UI.

Test automation frameworks are all about simulating user input.

Comment: @Rod: You might use a loop to try again until you you succeed if that's what you are asking now. That's probably a slightly nicer solution than sleeping in my opinion. You should make sure that you only try a maximum number of times though. Otherwise you may end up in an infinite loop.